# how to call jdialog from jinternalframe

Tags: java, swing

Can some one tell me how to call JDialog from a JInternalframe?

```
public class BSJFrameUpdateOnlineTrdDlg extends JInternalFrame {

public BSJFrameUpdateOnlineTrdDlg(JDesktopPane jdesk) { //constructor
    super("Backoffice Synchronization");
     jdeskTop = jdesk;
     frame = this;
    try {

      jbInit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setLocation(400, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(720, 570);

  }
private void jbInit() throws Exception {
//.......
 jButton1.addActionListener(new jButton1_upload_action());
this.getContentPane().add(jButton1, null);

}

 class jButton1_upload_action implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 displayDialog(frame,marketStatus);
}}

 public void displayDialog(JInternalFrame frame,String status){
     JDialog jdg = new JDialog();
     //this is where the JDIalog get initiated

}
}
```

this is what I'm currently having. I have inserted only most important code lines.

Comment: So what is your problem? You have code to create the dialog but you don't have code to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your already calling it? Are you just trying to make it visible?

```
public void displayDialog(JInternalFrame frame,String status){
     JDialog jdg = new JDialog();
     //...add the guts of the dialog
     jdg.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: opps.. now I got the point. In my code I had setVisible(true), not jdg.setVisible(true). I have changed it. Now it works fine. Earlier it doen't appear. thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 new customer_registration(null, true).setVisible(true);
```

customer_registration is another jdialog